# Minimum number of linear measurements

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a matrix  $A$ with null trace.

What is the minimum number of linear measurements that I have to perform in order to determine $A$?

By a linear measurement I mean that I know the quantities $A\vec x_i \cdot \vec h_j$ for given $\vec x_i$ and  $\vec h_j$

Comment: what do you mean by $Ax_i\cdot h_j$? What is your model? what are you inputs and outputs (assuming we already know you want $A$)?

Answer (score 0):

Using unit vectors for both parts of the measurement you have $e_i^TAe_j=A_{ij}$ so if “one measurement” corresponds to one unique pair $(\vec x_i,\vec h_i)$ then each measurement of this form will yield one entry of the matrix. For a generic $m\times n$ matrix you'd therefore need $m\cdot n$ measurements. Knowing the trace adds one linear constraint, so you can infer one value from all the others, i.e. $m\cdot n-1$ measurements. I can not imagine how a different choice of measurement vectors could do better than this.

On the other hand, where I wrote $(\vec x_i,\vec h_i)$ you had $(\vec x_i,\vec h_j)$. Were you thinking of combining a single $x$ vector with multiple $h$ vectors, or vice versa? If so, you will need $m$ vectors $\vec h_j$ and $n$ vectors $\vec x_i$, minus one combination due to the trace. I'll leave it to you to decide what you count as “one measurement” in this case.